YouTube IFrame API loadVideoById with startSeconds is failing
I have detected the startSeconds of loadVideoById not working recently. I saw it move to the time of that startSeconds but it'd immediately moved to the time of clip has played before, but I tested another clip B not playing before, the player seeking to the startSeconds, if I seek slider time of the clip B it's being the same failure when running script with startSeconds. It seems prioritize moving to the current position of video.
I give for example: if clip being stopped or playing at 01:48:27, the script run with startSeconds (03:46:58)
the player move to 03:46:58 then come back to 01:48:04 or less than few seconds right after that.
I think that a new bug of IFrame API.
Hope you fix that bug soon and supporting add clip with start time to a playlist in YouTube site.

Amending my previous answer - turns out to be a much easier solution.
If supplying player parameters, you need to supply them as a single dictionary. Both loadVideoById and cueVideoById take a single parameter which can be a video id or a dictionary of player parameters.
This will work:
player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': 0});

This will only take the videoId and discard the rest:
player.loadVideoById(videoId, startSeconds=0);

The YouTube api docs are awful.
